# WinSCP - exit code 3

Tags: winscp

I was not able to create a question on winscp.net because it was in read only mode, so I am posting here.  I appear to be having a problem with WinSCP that was supposed to have been fixed in version 5.2.5 (WinSCP tracker bug 999).  I am using WinSCP.exe version 5.9.5.7441 with WinSCPnet.dll version 1.3.7.7441 on a Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.  I have a .NET windows service that periodically opens a session to transfer files.  It was working fine for a while, but now it continuously fails with the error:

> WinSCP.SessionLocalException: WinSCP process terminated with exit code
>   3. There was no output. Response log file C:\Users \xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\wscp8A2C.0264DE91.tmp was not created. This
>   could indicate lack of write permissions to the log  folder or
>   problems starting WinSCP itself.    at
>   WinSCP.Session.Open(SessionOptions sessionOptions)

I saw this post [Why RegisterClass fails with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893366/why-registerclass-fails-with-error-not-enough-memory) that seems to be the cause, but I do not know how to resolve this.  I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Does restart of the machine solve the problem?

Comment: A restart of the windows service only did not solve the problem, but a restart of the machine did get it to work again.  I have since changed from using a .NET windows service to using a .NET console application that runs as a scheduled task, and it is now running on a different server that has less things running on it.  So far this approach has been working.

Comment: Isn't there another process using old version of WinSCP on that machine?

Comment: No, we just recently started using WinSCP, and I checked the versions.

Comment: So far the .NET console application running as a schedule task twice an hour, the error below has happened about 3 times a day.  I have not had to do anything for it to work after these failures.

Comment: System.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond - WinSCP has not responded in time.There was no output. Response log file C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\wscp3208.036C601B.tmp was not created. This could indicate lack of write permissions to the log folder or problems starting WinSCP itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just ephemeral, it can easily be to due to a temporarily overloaded server.

Try setting longer [`Session.Timeout`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#timeout).

Comment: So far that is the case, and the timeout error frequency is acceptable.  Going back to the original post where I was using a .NET Windows service, does this mean the WinSCP tracker bug 999 still exists?

Comment: No that was a different problem. With the bug WinSCP permanently depleted resources of the server and only system restart could release them.

Comment: OK, I thought because it had the same symptoms that it was the same problem.  For now running as a schedule task works, but later we may need to look for another solution to allow us to run from a windows service.  Thanks.